# SQL: Less invasive way to find difference between two distinct columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am specifically targeting SQL Server, but this information would be helpful if it exists for MySQL also. I have found how to create a column that calculates the difference between columns of two consecutive rows, but what I am interested in is **how do I calculate the difference between one column in two *distinctly* identifiable rows?**

I know of one way to do it, but it requires deep query nesting and repeating the same base queries. Suppose I have a large query joining multiple tables that ultimately boils down to this:

```
SELECT
    projectStatus AS [Project Status],
    COUNT(projectStatus) AS [# of Projects]
FROM
    projectList
GROUP BY projectStatus
```

And let's say it gives the following result:

```
Project Status | # of Projects
------------------------------
Delayed        |           167
Delayed Known  |            83
On Time        |            92
Ahead          |            86
```

What I would like to do is append a row that calculates the difference between the # of Projects value of rows Delayed and Delayed Known, then omits the Delayed row, like so:

```
Project Status | # of Projects
------------------------------
Delayed        |           167
Delayed Known  |            83
On Time        |            92
Ahead          |            86
Delayed Unknown|            84
```

Based on the first query, the way I have figured out how to do this looks like:

```
SELECT
    projectStatus AS [Project Status],
    COUNT(projectStatus) AS [# of Projects]
FROM
    projectList
GROUP BY projectStatus
UNION
SELECT
    'Delayed Unknown' AS [Project Status],
    SUM([Sum Val]) AS [# of Projects]
FROM (
    SELECT
        [# of Projects] *
        CASE
            WHEN [Project Status] = 'Delayed' THEN 1
            WHEN [Project Status] = 'Delayed Known'] THEN -1
            ELSE 0
        END AS [Sum Val]
    FROM (
        SELECT
            projectStatus AS [Project Status],
            COUNT(projectStatus) AS [# of Projects]
        FROM
            projectList
        WHERE 
            projectStatus IN ('Delayed', 'Delayed Known')
        GROUP BY projectStatus
    ) AS queryC
) AS queryB
```

*Keep in mind* that the inner query that this is based on is simplified for this post, but it actually is a larger query that is composed of its own `UNION`. Therefore, this gets ugly very quickly and approaches hard-to-maintain status.

The target for this query is to act as a dataset for SQL Server Reporting Services, so my constraint is to do this *all in one query* (unless it is possible to use temp tables within SSRS datasets). So, in one query, **is there a less invasive way to do this calculation?**

Comment: seems like you'd need a union or subquery.. some way to subtract the 2 counts.. since you mention SSRS, is this something you can just calculate in a report?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, may be you are looking for something like the below.

```
;with cte as(
    select Projectstatus, count(*) as [# of Projects]
    from @Table 
    where projectStatus IN ('Delayed', 'Delayed Known')
    group by ProjectStatus
), cte2 as(
    select 
        (Select [# of Projects] From cte Where Projectstatus = 'Delayed')
        -(Select [# of Projects] From cte Where Projectstatus = 'Delayed Known')  as DelayedUnKownProjects
)
    select Projectstatus, [# of Projects] 
    From cte
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Delayed UnKnown' as Projectstatus, DelayedUnKownProjects as [# of Projects]
    From cte2
```

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I wanted to do, and _so_ much more concise than the trickery I was trying to do. This absolutely works with SQL Server, but common table expressions are not supported by the MySQL that I am using (which is fine).